# Word meaning to scrutinize skeptically?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word I'm looking for is how one should be in order to avoid getting phished or scammed.  It's not specific to that circumstance, but I'll use it for the sake of easy context.

As in,

> She checked the URL before clicking, and avoided answering the
> question about her mother's maiden name, she was so _____!

Adjectives or verbs are fine.

Words that are close but not perfect include:

***Scrutiny***: it seems to be more about, i.e., looking over your work trying to find mistakes, and lacks the defensive connotation I'm looking for.

***Skepticism***: it also doesn't imply defensiveness in the way I'm thinking. It also doesn't imply savviness or correctness, i.e., climate skeptics.

***Suspicion*** is close, but is maybe TOO negative and sounds more like paranoia.  It should apply equally to not clicking on shady emails as it does to logging into your bank's website and checking the connection security. More about consistently paying attention.

Comment: Are you looking for scrutiny, which implies analysis, or for *hesitancy to trust*? I'm not sure you need a single word if you want to combine those concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Vigilant**. It's a word that exemplifies the fact that people are out there actively trying to get you and that you should be cautious:

> keeping careful watch for possible danger or difficulties. — [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/vigilant)

As in:

- [Is That Email Legitimate? Remain Vigilant by Spotting Email Phishing Scams](https://blog.totalprosource.com/is-that-email-legitimate-remain-vigilant-by-spotting-email-phishing-scams)

Comment: I think this is probably the best choice here.  It connotes caution, the presence of risk, but also attentiveness.

It's really not a word I should have had to ask for, but I was having a major tip-of-the-tongue moment!

Answer (score 2):

You could try the adjective [*prudent*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prudent) — characterized by, arising from, or showing prudence.

> *She checked the URL before clicking and avoided answering the question about her mother's maiden name, she was so prudent!*

Here’s the definition of the noun *prudence* (see especially **4**):

> **1** : the ability to govern and discipline oneself by the use of reason
>
> **2** : sagacity or shrewdness in the management of affairs
>
> **3** : skill and good judgment in the use of resources
>
> **4** : caution or circumspection as to danger or risk
>
> <sub>Source: [Merriam-Webster —
> *prudence*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prudence)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Leary.

> : SUSPICIOUS, WARY —often used with of
> leery of strangers
> She seemed a little leery of the proposal.

“Leary.” Merriam-Webster.com Dictionary, Merriam-Webster, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leary. Accessed 13 Jul. 2021.

Answer (score 0):

***Dubious*** is probably the most fitting adjective to use in this circumstance.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dubious

> 2b. questionable or suspect as to true nature or quality // *the practice is of dubious legality*

Answer (score -1):

***Circumspect*** could be a term you could use. It means:

> careful not to take risks:
>
> - Officials were circumspect about saying what the talks had achieved. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/circumspect))

About this term [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/circumspect) says:

> If you are *circumspect*, you think carefully before doing or saying
> anything. A good quality in someone entrusted with responsibility,
> though sometimes boring in a friend.
>
> The word circumspect was borrowed from Latin *circumspectus*, from
> *circumspicere*, "to be cautious." The basic meaning of Latin
> *circumspicere* is "to look around." Near synonyms are *prudent* and
> *cautious*, though ***circumspect*** ***implies a careful consideration of all
> circumstances and a desire to avoid mistakes and bad consequences***.

So your sentence would look like:

> She checked the URL before clicking, and avoided answering the question about her mother's maiden name, she was so *circumspect*!

There is also the noun *[circumspection](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/circumspection)*.

Comment: I'm not the downvote, but I think your discussion establishes that "circumspect" is LESS suspicious than "scrutinize." You taught me more about "circumspect" than I had known before. Thanks.

Comment: @Royster The definitions of "circumspect" emphasise rather the "careful consideration of all circumstances" in order not to take risks.